# NumPy reshape array in-place

Tags: python, numpy

I need to do an in-place resizing of a NumPy array, so I'd prefer `numpy.resize()` module to `numpy.reshape()`. I find that `numpy.resize()` return an array with wrong dimensions if I specify -1 in one of the dimensions of the required shape. Does anyone know why is it so? What is an alternative way to do in-place resizing of an array?

Answer (score 6):

The *in-place* resize you get with [`ndarray.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) does not allow for negative dimensions. You can easily check yourself:

```
a=np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])

a.resize((4,-1))
> ValueError: negative dimensions not allowed
```

In most of the cases, [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) will be returning a [view](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html) of the array, and hence there will be no unnecessary copying and additional memory allocation involved (though it doesn't modify the array in-place):

```
a_view = a.reshape(4,-1)
np.shares_memory(a, a_view)
# True
```

But even though `reshape` does not allow for in-place operations, what you can do is **assign the new shape to the shape attribute of the array**, which *does* allow for negative dimensions:

```
a.shape = (4,-1)
```

Which *is* an in-place operation, and just as efficient as `a.resize((4,1))` would be. Note that this method will raise an error when the reshape cannot be done without copying the data.

---

Here are some timings for efficiency comparison with a larger array, including the timings for reassigning from a view:

```
def inplace_reshape(a):
    a.shape = (10000,-1)

def inplace_resize(a):
    a.resize((10000,3))

def reshaped_view(a):
    a = np.reshape(a, (10000,-1))

def resized_copy(a):
    a = np.resize(a, (10000,3))
```

---

```
a = np.random.random((30000,1))

%timeit inplace_reshape(a)
# 383 ns ± 14.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit inplace_resize(a)
# 294 ns ± 20.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit reshaped_view(a)
# 1.5 µs ± 25.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit resized_copy(a)
# 21.5 µs ± 289 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Where both of them produce the same result:

```
b = np.copy(a)

a.shape = (10000,-1)
b.resize((10000,3))
np.array_equal(a,b)
# True
```