# Reshape not changing array's shape

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Codes are here:

```
a1 = np.random.permutation(10)
print("before :" + str(a1.shape))
a1.reshape((1,10))
print("after  :" + str(a1.shape))
```

Result:

```
before :(10,)
after  :(10,)
```

I'm so confused. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy's [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) does not modify the array in-place (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62321275/9698684) for an alternative). You can either [`ndarray.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html) (which does modify the shape `in-place` or assign the reshaped view to `a1` again:

```
a1 = np.random.permutation(10)

a1.reshape((1,10))
a1.shape
# (10,)

a1.resize((1,10))
a1.shape
# (1, 10)
```

Or alternatively

```
a1 = a1.reshape((1,10))
```